# Creating RESTful services in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

As I gone over the AWS Lambda documentation, there are references on triggering services based on AWS events. I do not see references on hosting services in Lambda.

Would like to understand whether is it possible to **create RESTful services using AWS Lambda** for web sites to consume or not?

I can use NodeJs to develop the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correction :

Amazon has launched - Amazon API Gateway which used Lambda

> What Is Amazon API Gateway?
>
> API Gateway helps developers deliver
> robust, secure, and scalable mobile and web application back ends. API
> Gateway allows developers to securely connect mobile and web
> applications to business logic hosted on AWS Lambda, APIs hosted on
> Amazon EC2, or other publicly addressable web services hosted inside
> or outside of AWS. With API Gateway, developers can create and operate
> APIs for their back-end services without developing and maintaining
> infrastructure to handle authorization and access control, traffic
> management, monitoring and analytics, version management, and software
> development kit (SDK) generation.
>
> API Gateway is designed for web and mobile developers who are looking
> to provide secure, reliable access to back-end APIs for access from
> mobile apps, web apps, and server apps that are built internally or by
> third-party ecosystem partners. The business logic behind the APIs can
> either be provided by a publicly accessible endpoint API Gateway
> proxies call to, or it can be entirely run as a Lambda function.

https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway

<strike>As of today; AWS Lambda is focused on working out / responding to events like S3 put, DynamoDB Streams and also custom events [ there could be more event sources expected from Amazon ] - with heavily leveraging the STATELESSNESS style of programming.</strike>

To build out a complete RESTful Service backend using AWS Lambda wouldn't be possible or in other words AWS Lambda would be a bad choice to build the RESTful Service. You can continue to use the NodeJS and make it run on top of EC2 or ElasticBeanstalk.

Comment: Ok, you highlight that Lambda leverage "STATELESSNESS" like it would be a problem. I'd like to remind, that correct REST is stateless.

Answer (score 8):

As of the last month, the answer has changed. AWS Lambda functions can now return a synchronous response and AWS is now encouraging the use of Lambda as a mobile backend or potentially a full REST API.

Documentation is a bit sparse at the moment, but you can start reading about it here for now:
http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/whatsnew/

Answer (score 7):

Amazon now supports this directly with the [API Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) service. [This post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-api-gateway-build-and-run-scalable-application-backends/) is a great rundown of how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Yes** it is possible to build RESTful services using AWS lambda for websites to consume.

**Your question has been answered by Tim Wagner of Amazon at a conference presentation where an audience member asks a very similar question to yours.**

**Question**

*"If you want to trigger a lambda function based on a regular old web request coming in from a user on the internet ... they hit an address and they sent in a bunch of query parameters ... So theres just this one stateless kind of thing that comes in with a bunch of data and then you want to trigger a lambda function off of that? ... what are the options there? ... to fire off that node.js workload?"*

**Answer 1**

*"... use something like beanstalk to create a web app. And then inside that webapp invoke the lambda functions for the portions of your workload or scenario that make sense to do"*

**Answer 2**

*"... If you're able to ... constrain your calls to match lambda's request model then you can skip that (beanstak webapp) and simply call us as if we were a web service proxy for you"*

https://youtu.be/copO_JQQsBs?t=50m53s

---

As for the node part of your question.

The answer is yes you can develop your Lambda function using node.js

Please refer to the Webinar from Amazon below.

*"The language that we have support for today is node.js"*

https://youtu.be/YEWtQsqIYsk?t=25m22s

Answer (score 0):

You can do almost anything (also very easily) with AWS Lambda. You can check out the below Serverless Framework: http://docs.serverless.com/v0.5.0/docs

Answer (score 0):

For JAVA you can use Lambada Framework: https://github.com/lambadaframework/lambadaframework